# add angular plugin into ionic 2 / angular 2 project

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

I'm learning Ionic 2 after I learned Ionic 1 for the past 2 weeks. In the weeks I learned Ionic 1 I made a app with a [calendar](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) with a plugin. I did the code of the calendar plugin in the www/lib folder.

But now by Ionic 2 the file structure is different and does someone know where I have to put the *.js and the *.css files into for that calendar plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your plugin is npm library, install using command **npm install package-name** inside the project folder. If it is not an npm package, follow the steps from [link](https://blog.nraboy.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/) to get it done.

Comment: It is not a npm package

Comment: Kindly follow the procedure in the link mentioned in the answer